# Solving for natural numbers: $x^{y}=y^{x-y}$

Tags: diophantine-equations

> Solve for natural numbers:
> $$x^{y}=y^{x-y}$$

What I have tried:

\begin{equation}
x>y \geqslant 2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{y}=y^{x-2 y}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}                
\frac{x}{y}=k, k \in N
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x=k y
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
(k y)^{y}=y^{k y-y} \Leftrightarrow k^{y} y^{y}=y^{k y-y} \Leftrightarrow k^{y}=y^{(k-2) y} \Leftrightarrow k=y^{k-2} .
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k=y^{k-2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
k \geqslant 2^{k-2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k<2^{k-2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
k \geqslant 5 
\end{equation}

How do I prove this statement?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that deals with the content of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions are
$(x, y)=
(1, 1),
(9, 3),
(8, 2)
$.

$x^y = y^{x-y}$
with
$x, y \ge 1$.

If $y=1$ then
$x=1$
which is a solution.

Assume $y \ge 2$.

If $x = y$ then
$y^y = 1$,
so $y = 1$.

If $x \lt y$ then
$x^y =1/y^{y-x}< 1$,
so no solutions.

Therefore $x > y \ge 2$.

$x
=y^{x/y-1}$
so $x/y-1 > 1$
or $x > 2y$.

$(xy)^y = y^x$.

Let
$(x, y) = d,
x = ad, y=db,
(a, b) = 1,
a > 2b$.

$(d^2ab)^{db} = (db)^{da},\\
(d^2ab)^{b} = (db)^{a},\\
d^{2b}(ab)^b = d^ab^a,\\
d^{2b}a^b = d^ab^{a-b},\\
a^b = d^{a-2b}b^{a-b}$.

Since
$(a, b) = 1$
and
$a > 2b$,
$b = 1$
(otherwise
$p | b\implies p|a$).

Therefore
$a = d^{a-2}$
or
$d = a^{1/(a-2)}$.
Since
$a > 2, a \ge 3$.

Let
$a = 3+c, c \ge 0$.
$d = (3+c)^{1/(1+c)}$.

If $c = 0, d=3, a=3,
x=9, y=3$.
$9^3 = 3^6$
which works.

If
$c = 1$ then
$d = 4^{1/2} = 2,
a=4, x=8, y=2,
8^2 = 2^6$
which works.

If $c =2$ then
$d = 5^{1/3}$
which is not an integer.

If $c \ge 2$
then
$1 < (3+c)^{1/(1+c)} < 2$
so there are no solutions.

$3+c \lt 2^{1+c}$
true for $c = 2$.
If
$2^{1+c} \gt 3+c$ then
$2^{1+c+1}
=2\cdot 2^{1+c}
\gt 2\cdot (3+c)
=3+c+3+2c
\gt 3+c+1
$.